# nodejs folder permissions for windows machine

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I am working in electron app and need to check if user can read, create and delete files from the folder. I tried fs.access with constants like W_OK, R_OK etc. also try to use fs.stats with stat-mode(npm package), all the permissions return true,

This is wrong, even user cannot access the files on the folder (as when user double click on the folder windows give message that user has not got rights to access the folder) and when try to create files in the folder using electron gives error that user cannot create files.

I do not want to create files and catch errors to check permission if possible, Am I missing anything, is this is known problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't check permissions before you access files. This is universally true for all file system operations. Just access the file. It will work - or not. Catch the error.

Comment: Thanks, what about delete rights, so i need to first create a file and then try to delete it to check delete rights.

Comment: You don't check rights *at all*. File systems are multi-threaded and there is no guarantee whatsoever that a thing that was true a nanosecond ago is true now. A rights check represents a moment in time. In the next moment (as short the next process tick in node) your rights might be gone. So the result of a rights check is inherently worthless. You cannot use it to make dependable predictions so therefore there is no reason to make it at all. Let it go. Delete the file. Handle the error.